# accessing AWS ELB from iframe getting Mixed Content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shiny, amazon-elb

So I have setup an EC2 instance for an R Shiny App, setup Route 43, Load Balancer, Target groups, listeners and everything is working great when I access the URL/instance directly from the browser, so I'm able to access it using http/https (https://example.com/shiny/rstudio). The issue im running into is that I have to make this request from an iFrame from on separate domain.

The domain/website the iframe is on, is HTTPS, and my iFrame looks like this:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://example.com/shiny/rstudio?key=7178946820872" width="1200" height="950" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

But it doesn't work, I get the Mixed Content error in the console:

```
    Mixed Content: The page at 'https://website.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but requested an insecure frame 'http://example.com/shiny/rstudio/?key=7178946820872'.
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

What confuses me is that in my iFrame, the src is HTTPS, but for some reason in the error its saying HTTP.

I have tried a bunch of things like tweaking the security groups, attributes on the load balancer, but I can't figure it out.